# Oracle_fdw not accessing Oracle database from Aurora PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, amazon-aurora, oracle-fdw

I'm trying to connect to an active Oracle database via **oracle_fdw** extension on Aurora PostgreSQL instance.
The latest attempt at creating a server was:

```
CREATE SERVER foreign_oracle 
        TYPE 'Oracle12' 
        VERSION '12' 
        FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER oracle_fdw 
OPTIONS (dbserver '//xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1521/xxx');
```

After creating foreign table, `select *` on the table returns the following error, no matter how I format the connection string:

> SQL Error [HV00N]: ERROR: connection for foreign table "oratab"
> cannot be established   Detail: ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not
> currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

Additional info:

- same Oracle db can be accessed with dbeaver/psql
- outbound rule for Aurora is set to everything
- I haven't tried using sqlplus because I want to avoid installing Oracle

Comment: Simple: there is no service `xxx` registered at the Oracle listener on xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, port 1521.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't reading carefully enough. Also, we had wrong credentials (SID and Service Name got mixed up)